# Create kable table with fully-colored background

Tags: r, kable

I'm having trouble creating a nicely formatted table in `R`. I'm 90% of the way there, but can't get all the way.

I need to color the entire cell with a background color as seen in the example below. I read the `kable` vignette and saw that in html format, `background` does not color the whole cell. Is there a way to get around this? I tried setting it to latex instead, but the output is in latex rather than shown in the viewer. I'm also a novice `markdown` user so when I tried it there, the output was not what I was hoping for (which is simply a self-contained table).

I've done tons of searching on SO for a solution, but I haven't been able to get it. It sure isn't easy to produce tables in `R`. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Indicator = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5"
), Sign = c(-1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L), Freq = c("M", "A", "Q", "M", 
                                            "M")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Indicator  Sign Freq 
  <chr>     <int> <chr>
1 Var1         -1 M    
2 Var2          1 A    
3 Var3          1 Q    
4 Var4         -1 M    
5 Var5          1 M
```

Attempted code:

```
library(kable)
library(kableExtra)
df  %>% 
      dplyr::rename(Trend = Freq) %>%
      mutate(Indicator = cell_spec(Indicator, "html", color = "black", bold = T), 
             Trend = cell_spec(Trend, "html", color = "white", bold = T, 
                               background = factor(Sign, c(-1, 0, 1), 
                                                   c("red", "gray", "green")))) %>%
      select(Indicator, Trend) %>%
      kable(align = c('l', 'c'), format = "html", escape = F) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("bordered", full_width = F, font_size = 16)) %>% 
      row_spec(0, background = "rgb(172, 178, 152)", color = "black", font_size = 18)
```

[image: Output Table]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with `kable`/`kableExtra`, you might need to look at [formattable](https://renkun-ken.github.io/formattable/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified the initial data to be clear:

```
df <- tribble(~Indicator, ~Freq, ~cellColor,
              'Speed', 43.342, 'red',
              'Altitude', 44.444, 'blue',
              'Smartness', 0.343, 'green')
```

To success, we need to create the table object (`tbl`), because the `kable` library has function `column_spec` for the fixed column width setting.

```
tbl <- df %>% 
  mutate(Indicator = cell_spec(Indicator, "html", color = "black", bold = T), 
         Freq = cell_spec(x = Freq, 
                           format = "html", 
                           color = "white", 
                           bold = T, 
                           extra_css = paste(paste('background-color', cellColor, sep = ': '), # combine background-color CSS rule with the observation vector value
                                             'display: inline-block', # extremely important CSS modifier for the span tag in the table cell
                                             'text-align: center', # text align
                                             'padding: 0px', # expand the field of text
                                             'margin: 0px', # expand the field of text
                                             'width: 200px', # future cell/column width
                                             sep = "; "), # CSS notation rule
                           )
  ) %>%
  select(-cellColor) %>% # exclude cellColor vector
  kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("bordered", full_width = F, font_size = 16))

column_spec(tbl, 2, width = "200px") # set the column width as the cell width

tbl # print
```

As one can see, it is important to match the column and cell size. As an example, I made both of them 200px wide.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Weird that this is not doable, even in other packages. I did a quick search based on your answer and this can't even be done in straight css. Some kind of html issue or something I guess. Guess I need to learn markdown. In any case, this is currently the best solution right now, so I picked it as the correct one. Thanks for your help.